# Theory using First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The definition of theory is:

> In mathematical logic, a theory (also called a formal theory) is a set
>   of sentences in a formal language

So, if i use the First Order Logic formal system, a theory is practically an instance of senteces obtained using the First Order Logic formal system.
So, i can create infinite many theories using this formal system.
Is it that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although I have seen some texts (e.g. Boolos and Jeffrey) define a theory as not just any set of sentences, but a set of sentences that is closed under logical consequence, i.e. every sentence that is a logical consequence of that set of sentences is contained in the set.

Either way, there can be an infinite number of possible theories. For example, the language of first-order logic is typically assumed to have an infinite number of predicates, and thus for every 1-place predicate $P$ you can consider the theory $\{ \exists x P(x) \}$ (or the (infinite) set of all sentences that are consequences of $\exists x P(x)$), and since for any two different predicates $P$ and $Q$ the statements $\exists x P(x)$ and $\exists x Q(x)$ are not logical consequences of each other, you immediately get an infinite number of different theories that way.

Comment: So, isnt sufficient to instantiate the axioms scheme F (i also have inference rules) to obtain a theory ?

Comment: @Tantaros Hmm, I believe different texts define theories a little different. I see that the Wikipedia article defines a theory like you said: just any set of sentences. But I have seen theories defined using the 'closed under logical consequence' part as well ...

Comment: I think is it implicit. Once i use an axiom scheme and the inference rules , what i have is your definition

Comment: @Tantaros Assuming the inference rules are sound and complete, yes.

Comment: What do you mean for "sound" ?

Comment: @Tantaros that you don't have inference rules that allow you to infer things that are not in fact logical consequences.

Comment: and "complete" ?

Comment: @Tantaros An inference system is complete iff it is able to infer all logical consequences. Here's one way to think about it: Define $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ as: $\varphi$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$. Define $\Gamma \vdash_S \varphi$ as: using the inference rules of inference system $S$, you can derive $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$. With that, soundness of $S$ means: for any $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$: if $\Gamma \vdash_S \varphi$ then $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$. Completeness means:  if $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ then $\Gamma \vdash_S \varphi$. Any 'normal' inference will be both sound and complete.